# Accessing a Map<String, Interface-Impl> which is not configurable in root object graph in Guice

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

I want to know what is the equivalent for the below Spring usage

```
@Autowired
Map<String,KeyWordExecutor> keyWordExecutors;
```

From what I undestand of Guice, I am supposed to use an injector only at the bootstrapping part and not anywhere else. If I want to instantiate an implementation of interface based on runtime input inside at some level of my object graph, how should i do that ?

Below is some simple code indicative of what I want to achieve and how I do it with spring. I think Spring's package-scan helps me to autowire random  maps and I want to know how to do it in Guice.

```
Interface RuleExecutor
{...}

Interface KeyWordExecutor
{...}
```

SPRING BASED CODE

```
Class StandardRuleExecutor implements RuleExecutor
{
    @Autowired
    Map<String,KeyWordExecutor> keyWordExectors;

    @Override
    public void execute(List<String> rules)
    {
        int val = 0;
        foreach(String rule : rules)
        {
            String keyword = getKeyWord(rule);
            val = keyWordExecutors.get(keyword).execute(val, rule)
        }
    }
}

Class ApplicationLauncher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemApplicationContext("bindings.xml");
        RuleExecutor ruleExecutor = context.getBean("executor");
        ruleExecutor.execute(args);
    }
}
```

GUICE BOOTSTRAP

```
Class ApplicationLauncher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.getInjector(new RulesExecutorModule())
        RuleExecutor ruleExecutor = injector.getInstace(RuleExecutor.class);
        ruleExecutor.execute(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you look at https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings ?

Comment: One reason your post got so little attention is that you didn't tag java... by not tagging Java you are going to get a lot fewer views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [`MapBinder`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) is for. From your post, it seems as if the Spring way is much easier, but the Spring way also has a big xml file, a step that's conveniently ommitted :)

In Guice, you would do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(RuleExector.class).to(StandardRuleExecutor.class); // Don't forget this one :)

    MapBinder mb = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, KeyWordExecutor.class);
    mb.addBinding("foo").to(FooKeyWordExecutor.class);
    mb.addBinding("bar").to(BarKeyWordExecutor.class);
    // etc.
}
```

Then just do:

```
class StandardRuleExecutor implements RuleExecutor {
    @Inject Map<String, KeyWordExecutor> keyWordExectors;

    // The rest of your code is the same
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton.